# If one checkbox is checked, force the other one to check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code and trying to force it to update another checkbox if the current checkbox is ticked.
For reference, I've checked and confirmed that the other checkbox in fact has the ID att_$var, but it's not updating... What have I done wrong?

```
    $('.colour-input').each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                colourArray.push($(this).val());
                colourArray.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
            } else {
            var index = colourArray.indexOf($(this).val());
            if (index > -1) {
                colourArray.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
            $.ajax({
            url: "php/ColourArrayHandle.php",
            // The successful jQuery process will be handled through ajax and PHP.
            });
        });
    });
```

EDIT: I have got the following code to work when added inside of the above function, but I'm still not 100% why this works and my old one didn't. If someone can walk me through why it's necessary to call $($var).each(function () {}); again I'd love to learn :)

```
$(presentID).each(function () {
                    if(this.checked){
                        console.log("The box was checked.");
                    } else {
                        console.log("The box is not checked.");
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the result value of your ajax call through the success function if that is what you are trying to achieve.

```
success: function(teamColour){
    console.log(colourArray+ " " +teamColour);
}
```

Edit:

If checkbox two is checked, it calls function tow and assuming it takes 2 seconds (more or less) to call the ajax and returns the result. Once the result is in, it checks checkbox one and triggers function one. On the other hand, if initially checkbox one is checked, it just runs the function one.
If the ajax data is irrelevant and you want to run both functions at once, you can remove the async await and call the function one immediately.

```
<label>
  <input class="colour-input colour-input-one" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" /> Checkbox 1 
</label>
<label>
  <input class="colour-input colour-input-two" type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" /> Checkbox 2 
</label>



function one() {
    console.log('Function One Called')
    $('.colour-input').prop('disabled', false)
}
async function two() {
    await setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Function Two Called');
        $('.colour-input-one').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
        $('.colour-input').prop('disabled', false)
    }, 2000);
}

$('.colour-input').on('change', function() {
    $('.colour-input').prop('disabled', true)
    $(this).hasClass('colour-input-two') ? two() : one();
})
```

Comment: The ajax is somewhat irrelevant in this case, because the ajax function is working (other than the console.log which you may have helped with - thanks!)... What I'm trying to do basically is have two checkboxes side by side. When checkbox 1 is checked, it runs the function. The end. When checkbox two is checked, it runs its respective function but also automatically checks checkbox 1 and runs checkbox 1's function.

Comment: Why not make it simple and call separate functions based on each checkbox? I added the edit section.

Comment: So in the big picture, I'm trying to do an attendance checklist where you are marked present, but it also records if you were wearing your team colour. My goal is to make it so that when the person taking attendance records that you are wearing the team colour, you are automatically marked present (separate checkboxes and separate ajax/SQL handlers) My code as it stands is coming back false every time "The box is not checked"